# How to change a flat section of a mesh into a smooth curved one

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I have this mesh:

[image]

It's crossed shape; what I want is to turn the inner flat sections into smooth curved ones (white marks showing what I mean).
How can I do this?

Comment: Delete all the edges except the one on the corner. Select it, bevel it with a smooth profile and multiple segments.

Comment: Both solutions are correct but in my case the first one is better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a similar model you already have, you can use "smooth vertex":

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @OmarAhmad start with a basic shape with no subdivision and then you can use the Bevel tool.

Select the corner edge and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel.

Then use the tools options to set the number of segments and further refine the shape.

[image]